# Issue with "Handleonclose" functionality on jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp file which calls another jsp file opening it as a showmodal dialog window.

Say file1.jsp calls file2.jsp through file1.js.

File1.jsp-->File1.js (respective js files)
File2.jsp-->File2.js(respective js files)

Now to handleonclose in File2.jsp I added a function in File2.js.

When I hit close window but choose option as cancel, instead of just showing the old window. 
It shows a modal window ontop of the existing modal window. Why is this happening. Am I missing something obvious.

What i expect to happen: When I choose Close but click cancel, nothing should happen.

File2.js function:

```
function handleOnClose() {

    var resultsDoc = document.frames('searchBuffer').document;

    if (event.clientY < 0) {
        var bool = confirm('Are you sure you want to close the window ?');
        if (!bool) { //Issue occurs here
            window.showModalDialog("File2.jsp", "", "dialogWidth:1000px;dialogHeight:650px");
        }
        else {
            resultsDoc.all('searchResults').innerText = '';

            document.someSearch.submit();
        }
    }

    window.returnValue = 'Discard';

}
```

Comment: It's showing a new modal window because you've told it to by calling `window.showModalDialog ( "File2.jsp" , "" , "dialogWidth:1000px;dialogHeight:650px" );` when they click the "Cancel" option. If you want nothing to happen then you don't want to be doing something.

Comment: hey Anthony, thanks for replying... but if i remove that line, and do the cancel it merely closes the old modal window as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified File2.js function:

```
function handleOnClose() {

    var resultsDoc = document.frames('searchBuffer').document;

    if (event.clientY < 0) {
        var bool = confirm('Are you sure you want to close the window ?');
        if (!bool) { //Issue occurs here
            //*******removed the showmodal dialog window call
              window.returnValue = 'Sorry';
        }
        else {
            resultsDoc.all('searchResults').innerText = '';

            document.someSearch.submit();
    window.returnValue = 'Discard';
        }
    }

}
```

On the calling js (file1.js) I check if return value is "Discard" if so I refresh the page.
Otherwise I call the showmodal window again. My result is stored in the buffer so retrieval isn't a problem. Works like a charm